# Angular Material Design layout that wraps content

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

How to achieve the following layout (with "plus" icon below the card layout) ? :

[image]

I tried the following code :

```
    <section layout="column" style="background-color: black;">

        <md-card flex="100">
            <md-card-header style="background-color: greenyellow; ">
                <h2>Card headline</h2>
            </md-card-header>
            <md-card-content class="inline">
                Card content
            </md-card-content>

        </md-card>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
<div class="demo" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class="md-padding" flex-gt-xs="50">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center">
      <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
          ...
        </md-card-title>
      </md-card>

      <md-button class="md-fab" aria-label="Eat cake">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/cake.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

[Here's a Codepen](http://codepen.io/spectrus/pen/OXLpoV) modified from one of the original card examples.